# How can I prevent rabbits from entering my property under a vinyl fence?

Tags: concrete, pest, soil

The objective is to stop rabbits from wandering inside my backyard. They do it before even moving the seedlings outdoors, and survival of anything (other than spiny roses and raspberries) would be a lost cause.

If not concrete, how might I close this hole?

[image: rabbit hole under fence]

Comment: Put cement there, what is to stop them from digging over a few inches/feet?  Will probably need a metal barrier dug down into the ground, around the fence.

Comment: It would be far more efficient to protect your seedlings/plants with a rabbit fence - metal mesh with openings not much bigger than 1", say 18"-24" high. Chicken wire works well, but is rather ugly and unpleasant to handle.

Answer (score 2):

You won't keep rabbits out with anything short of a full-length barricade well below grade under the entire fence. It's not a practical goal (nor do I understand the human inclination to completely detach ourselves from much of nature).

Put your plants in a dedicated enclosure or on an elevated platform.